# ALSA - Traktor Audio 2 - How to split front and rear stereo channels / How to debug dmix

Tags: fedora, udev, alsa, pulseaudio

I am struggling to persuade ALSA to separate the front and rear outputs of my Native Instruments Traktor Audio 2 external USB soundcard and would really appreciate help.

USB Vendor ID: 17cc, USB Product ID: 1330. Noted as I suspect there are different generations of the card (more in footnote).

Fedora 23.

Relevant ALSA FAQ - [**splitting front and rear outputs**](http://alsa.opensrc.org/Splitting_front_and_rear_outputs_.asoundrc), .asoundrc as per FAQ copied below.

As you'll guess - the problem is that it is not working for me.

I am after any help you can be provide, but the questions that come to mind are:

1. Is there a way to via logs to debug ALSA's card configuration and read of the .asoundrc?
2. If I was to start afresh and create a new .asoundrc -- how would I figure out the bindings, ttable, etc, settings?

I *know* the card can output separately as it is splitable at the pulseaudio level using [**these instructions**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Splitting_front.2Frear).

.asoundrc

```
    pcm.dshare {
        type dmix
        ipc_key 2048
        slave {
            pcm "hw:0"
            rate 44100
            period_time 0
            period_size 1024
            buffer_size 8192
            channels 4
        }
        bindings {
            0 0
            1 1
            2 2
            3 3
        }
    }
    pcm.frontx {
        type plug
        slave {
            pcm "dshare"
            channels 4
        }
        ttable.0.0 1
        ttable.1.1 1
    }
    pcm.rearx {
        type plug
        slave {
            pcm "dshare"
            channels 4
        }
        ttable.0.2 1
        ttable.1.3 1
    }
```

`aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: MK2 [Traktor Audio 2 MK2], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Adjustments tried...

```
pcm "hw:0"      to reflect card on "hw:3" - also tried "hw:3,0", "hw:3,0,0" 
pcm "hw:0"      to name rather than number "hw:MK2" - also tried "hw:MK2,0", "hw:MK2,0,0" 
pcm "hw:0"      to plughw rather than hw - "plughw:3" and "plughw:MK2"
```

Additional notes on suspicion  of older generations with different internals:

1. Mixxx Wiki page for Traktor Audio 2 with .asoundrc appears to refer to two sub-devices ("hw:TraktorAudio2,0,0" and "hw:TraktorAudio2,0,1"); where as I believe I only have one. I believe this as using these instructions only results in one selectable card named djA in Mixxx and `aplay -l` states the card only has one sub-device.
2. udev has a pulseaudio configuration file, `native-instruments-traktor-audio2.conf` that is referenced from `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-pulseaudio.rules` if the device's vendor ID is 17cc and product ID 041d. Same vendor, different ID to my card (1330).

Comment: Show the output of `aplay -l`.

Comment: Added to the post with an edit. @CL.

Comment: `hw:3` or `hw:MK2` would be correct. What is the error message when you try to use `aplay` with the `frontx`/`rearx` devices?

Comment: @CL - I'd not tried aplay with frontx and rearx before, and had working on the basis they do not appear as selectable devices in Mixxx. Now that I have tried -- I can output separately to frontx/rearx without error, but with audible clicks/noise, which may be due to the defaults? Additionally the rearx and frontx devices are still not visible in Mixxx.

Comment: @CL - scratch that. What I do have in Mixxx is the 'dshare' device, that I can select for both Master and Headphones and then select 'Channels 1 - 2' for Master and '3 - 4' for Headphones. I had been expecting rearx and frontx and had not noticed dshare. I am not 100% sure but I think this is it sorted. Thank you CL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These device definitions are correct.

The `buffer_size` is rather small; consider increasing it to be more safe against underruns (but also with larger latency).

To make a device show up in the device list, it needs a name hint:

```perl
pcm.hw_plus {
    type ...
    slave ...
    ...
    hint.description "My little device, with more cowbell"
}
```

Comment: I think the device not showing up may have been me -- frontx and rearx are there if I scroll down in the selection box, I just had not noticed the scrollbar in Mixxx's UI! However, when selected there is a problem... I get a very nasty drilling noise from the outputs, no matter which channel selection/combo between 1-4 I try. Additionally, should the 'hint.description' adjust how the pcm appears in the Mixxx list, as I still just get the pcm name?

Comment: Probably Mixxx does not use these name hints.

Comment: I think I've found my problem -- a jog wheel on the physical hardware controls the balance of main mixed into the headphone output. Having fiddled, if I take .asoundrc out of the picture and select 'Traktor Audio 2 MK2' and  'Channels 1 - 2' and '3 - 4' in Mixxx, I get the split I am after.
The problem in this question -- how to split into two ALSA pcm dev using .asoundrc -- still exists, as I get noise if I use frontx/rearx, but it is not a problem for me if I can split the outputs without it. 

Unless there is a sound quality benefit of pursuing this further? 

Appreciate the help @CL.